# Does polynomial of degree $0$ exist?

Tags: polynomials

Can I say $f(x)\equiv C$ is a polynomial of degree $0$ ? Here $C$ is any constant including 0.

**My Attempt** :  If it is a polynomial , then it will not have any root in the case of $C$ being non-zero. So it is violating Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. As this theorem guarantees atleast one root for every polynomial.

If $C$ is zero then any real number is root of this polynomial. That will violate Fundamental theorem of algebra.

Therefore , I am not sure if $f(x)\equiv C$ is a polynomial of degree $0$.

Can anyone please correct me if I have gone wrong anywhere ?

Comment: C is a polynomial of degree $0$ for $C\ne 0$, because it can be written as $Cx^0$, while the polynomial $0$ is considered to have degree $-\infty$.

Comment: In the case of C being zero ,  any real number is zero of the polynomial. Is it right ?@Tavish

Comment: In the case of C being non-zero ,  f does not have any root. But Fundamental theorem guarantees of at least one root for any polynomial.

Comment: The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra only applies to non-constant polynomials; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) for full statement.

Comment: Yes thank You@angryavian

Comment: In practice, the number of roots (including repeats) equals the degree of the polynomial.  Zero degree means zero roots.

Comment: But when C = 0 , it becomes basically a function which is zero for all real number. Then how can you say it will not have any root ?@herb steinberg

Comment: @sani Yes ${}{}$

Comment: Normally, the degree of the polynomial is determined by the largest non-negative integer $n$ such that the coefficient of $x^n$ is non-zero.  This is why the polynomial $5 \times x^{0}$ is construed to have degree $0$, while the polynomial $0 \times x^{0}$ is not so construed.  The equation $5 \times x^0 = 0$ has $0$ roots, while (as you indicated), the equation $0 \times x^0 = 0$ has an infinite number of roots.